# Does Percival have any magical power if nobody has "hope" in him?

Tags: seven-deadly-sins

Percival's magical power is called "hope".  When his friends have hope in him, his magical power increases. What happens if nobody has hope in him?

Does Percival have any magical power if nobody has "hope" in him?